# Reducir Id's / codigo en javacript

Tags: javascript, html

hola supongamos que tengo este codigo:

```js
function sumar() {
  // Asigno valor inicial de 0
  var v1 = 0;
  var v2 = 0;
  var v3 = 0;

  // Les cambio el valor si marche los checkbox
  if (document.getElementById("cb1").checked) {
    v1 = 10;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("cb2").checked) {
    v2 = 15;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("cb3").checked) {
    v3 = 20;
  }
  
  // Sumo las variables
  resultado = v1 + v2 + v3;
  
  // Envio el resultado a un label en html
  document.getElementById("total_label").innerHTML = resultado.toFixed(2);

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1">+ 10<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2">+ 15<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3">+ 20<br>

<button onclick="sumar()"> sumar </button><br>
<p><label id="total_label">0.00</label></p>
```

El problema es que mi codigo original tiene como 15 checkbox y creo que esta siendo demaciado inpractico tenerlos todos asi, hay alguna forma de hacer un arreglo con todos los checkbox o algo asi?

me serviria de mucho su ayuda :b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La opción más viable es ponerle una clase específica todos los *input*, lo cual hará que podamos acceder a todos ellos con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), usando [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Este método nos devuelve una lista de nodos, los cuales podemos recorrer con [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
Document: <p>Hello world</p>
Input: document.querySelectorAll("p");
Output: NodeList(1) [p]
```

Si no quieres colocarle una clase, puedes directamente obtener todos los *input* que sean *checkbox*

```js
function sumar() {
  let resultado = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]") /* Cambiar el selector a ".clase" si se usa una clase */.forEach((el,i) => {
    const valores = [10, 15, 20]; // Valores a sumar por cada checkbox
    if (el.checked) {
      resultado += valores[i]; // Obtener los valores seleccionados
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("total_label").innerHTML = resultado.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input class="box" type="checkbox" id="cb1">+ 10<br>
<input class="box" type="checkbox" id="cb2">+ 15<br>
<input class="box" type="checkbox" id="cb3">+ 20<br>

<button onclick="sumar()"> sumar </button><br>
<p><label id="total_label">0.00</label></p>
```

Comment: este esta bueno creo que si entiendo que hace cada cosa voy a probar a hacer algo asi muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear las casillas de selección dinámicamente a partir de un arreglo; incluso agregar el valor como un atributo. Y al momento de sumar lo sigues manejando como arreglo, pero de casillas.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function(event){
        [10,15,20].forEach(
            function(num){
                var chk = document.createElement("input");
                chk.type = "checkbox"
                chk.name = "cb[]";
                chk.setAttribute("int-val", num);
                chk.addEventListener('change',function(){sumar();});

                var div = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
                div.appendChild( chk );
                div.appendChild( document.createTextNode("+"+num) );
                div.appendChild( document.createElement("br") );                
            }
        );
    }
);

function sumar() {
    var resultado = 0;
    document.getElementsByName("cb[]").forEach(
        function(cb){
            if(cb.checked)
                resultado += parseInt(cb.getAttribute("int-val"));
        }
    );
    
    document.getElementById("total_label").innerHTML = resultado.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="checkboxes"></div>
<p><label id="total_label">0.00</label></p>
```

Comment: omg!! no lo habia visto es genial, y puedo añadir los checkbox directo en [10,15,20,60,80].forEach( esta muy padre investigare bien como funciona todo, muchas gracias :)